# Everyone has brown eyes

Tags: logic, induction

I'm going to prove that everyone's eyes are the same color. Ready?

If there is only one person, then it's obviously true; this person's eyes are the same color that this person's eyes.

Suppose it is established that $(n-1)$ persons must have the same eye color. Consider $n$ persons: the $(n-1)$ first have the same eye color, and the $(n-1)$ last have the same eye color. Since the two overlap, everyone has the same eye color.

My initialization is verified, and so is my induction. Since I have brown eyes, everyone has brown eyes. Wait a minute, what?

Comment: This is the classical "every horse is the same color" problem.  Variant thereof is covered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541852/basic-induction-probs

Comment: Just when reading this question, the votes were - $$2\to1\to0\to1$$

Comment: @anorton Sorry I didn't find this one, I just voted to close the post. Should I delete it instead?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Since it has an upvoted answer, you cannot delete it.  It's probably better to close instead of delete, anyway; if it's closed as a dup., then there will be an obvious link between this question and the other one.  Then, if someone googles "eye problem mathematical induction," they can easily find the answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works except when $n=2$.

That's why one can say that if any TWO people have eyes of the same color, then everyone's eyes have the same color.

Two commonplace forms of mathematical induction are these:

- The case $n=1$ is trivial, and the hard part is the induction step;
- The case $n=1$ is vacuously true; the induction step is trivial and relies on the case $n=2$ *and* on the induction hypothesis; and the hard part is the case $n=2$.

Your proof is of the second kind.

Comment: Hahaha, it took me a moment to figure out, good job :) I thought the post would be useful to others.