# The pencils in a box of crayons always have the same color

Tags: logic, induction

I retrieved an old math book and I'm delighted to share following exercise.

> **The pencils in a box of crayons always have the same color.**

Proof by induction on the number $n$ of pencils in the box:

- This is true when $n=1$. All the pencils, only one, havs the same color.
- Suppose the result true for a box having $n+1$ crayons. Remove one. Remains $n$ crayons. By induction hypothesis they all have the same color. Put back the crayon you removed and remove another one. The $n$ remaining crayons in the box have again the same color by induction hypothesis. Hence the two crayons that were removed have the same color. Therefore all the $n+1$ crayons have the same color.

*Can you find what's wrong here?*

Comment: the second part of reasoning doesn't work for $n=2$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color

Comment: Why should there be any pencils at all? The second step assumes you have $n+1$ crayons, not pencils.

Comment: Duplicate of [basic induction probs](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541852/basic-induction-probs), and see also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428151/questions-on-all-horse-are-the-same-color-proof-by-complete-induction).

Comment: You may find this thread about [Fake Induction Proofs](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196303/fake-induction-proofs) to be quite interesting.

Comment: that "hence" ...